# Getting error while running Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

Tags: android, android-volley

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/44.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/47.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/48.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/49.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/50.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/51.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/52.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/53.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/55.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/56.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/57.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/58.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/59.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/60.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/61.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/62.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/63.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/64.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/65.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/67.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/68.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/69.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/70.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/71.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/72.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/73.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/74.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/75.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/76.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/77.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/78.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/79.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/80.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/82.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/83.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/84.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/85.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/87.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/88.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/89.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/90.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/91.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/92.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/93.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/94.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/95.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/96.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/97.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/98.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/100.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/101.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/102.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/103.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/104.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/105.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/106.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/107.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/108.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/109.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/110.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/111.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/112.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/113.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/114.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/115.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/116.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/117.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/118.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/119.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/120.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/121.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/122.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/123.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/124.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/125.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/126.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/127.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/128.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/129.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/130.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/131.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/132.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/133.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/134.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/135.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/136.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/137.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/138.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/139.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/140.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/141.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/142.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/143.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/144.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/145.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/146.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/147.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/148.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/149.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/150.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/151.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/152.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/153.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/154.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/155.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/156.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/157.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/160.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/161.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/162.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/163.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/164.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/165.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/166.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/167.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/168.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/169.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/170.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/171.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/172.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/173.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/174.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/175.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/177.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/178.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/179.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/180.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/181.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/182.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/183.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/184.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/185.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/186.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/187.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/188.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/189.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/190.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/191.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/192.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/193.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/194.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/195.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/196.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/197.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/198.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/199.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/200.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/201.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/202.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/203.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/204.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/205.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/206.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/207.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/208.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/209.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/210.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/211.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/212.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/213.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/214.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/215.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/216.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/217.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/218.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/219.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/220.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/221.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/222.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/223.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/224.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/225.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/226.jar, /Users/muskannarang/Downloads/tranxit_android_provider/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/227.jar
>     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>     Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

Comment: Please post your Build.gradle files... both App level as well as module level...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just marge dependency on AndroidX Library.

Example: app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

to:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Than rebuild again, shows many errors. just comment out these old libraries. re-import android x library package. 
Example below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Marge AndroidX: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

I hope solved.